# Upgrade to Excel 2007 - app still uses 2003 interop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel

I have a windows forms application that uses excel to generate some reports.
Untill now it used 2003 but i've made an upgrade to use 2007. I have installed on my machine 2003, 2007 and 2010, and my app references Microsoft.office.core, v 12.0 and microsoft.office.interop.excel v 12.0.
But in my code, when i do :

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
......
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
string v = excelApp.Version;
```

v will be 11.0 .
Also, the path references

```
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll
```

How can this happen?
Any ideea how could i fix it ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't keep both versions (at least on your dev machine).On your clients machine it shouldn't be a problem . Normally in this situation your code should load the 2007 PIAs. I suggest that you should do a repair . Or do a complete fresh install of 2007.Or fiddle wth the registry and set the active version to 12 (which I don't recommend)

Comment: If you are developing applications for users you need to test with the versions they are using so you need access to the full set of versions.  I am sure it was @Siddharth Rout who suggested installing each version on a separate virtual PC.  Perhaps he will post an answer telling you how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this topic lately, maybe it would be useful for you too: [Trying to do Office Automation with Excel 2007, but keeps using Excel 2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239472/trying-to-do-office-automation-with-excel-2007-but-keeps-using-excel-2003).